# Open an Excel file, run a macro, save it (overwrite)

Tags: vba, excel, save

I'm currently trying to create a .vbs which

1. opens Excel
2. runs macro
3. saves it with new information
4. quits

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\test\test.xlsm", 0, True) 

xlApp.Run "test"
xlbook.Save
xlBook.Close False
set xlBook = Nothing

xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Upload is Finished"
WScript.Quit
```

I get the 'Upload is finished', but the macro is not saved. What am I doing wrong?

The macro is simply putting something from one worksheet to another:

```
Sub test()
'
' test Macro
'
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1:A10").Select
    Range("A10").Activate
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: change `xlBook.Close False` to `xlBook.Close`

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity why a macro in Excel? If you are controlling Excel via the object, why not have the macro code in there also?

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\test\test.xlsm", 0, True) 

xlbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10").Cut
xlbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Previous.Select
xlbook.Range("A2").Paste
xlbook.Save
xlBook.Close False
set xlBook = Nothing

xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Upload is Finished"
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Because it's not 'actual movement' of that macro I'm interested in, but being able to 1) open excel  2) run macro 3) save process what I was interested in. The actual macro I need to use for this process is rather big. If I can do it with a small macro, I should be able to do this process with a small macro. I will give this macro a shot :)

Answer (score 2):

```
xlBook.Close False
```

means "close and don't save changes".  Maybe you want

```
xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: OP is saving right before closing, I do this also as I have run into problems when saving on close before. I can't remember the specifics but it was throwing up another question I found that saving it before allowed me to pass in the params it required to suppress the question.

Comment: The xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=True returns an error when I run the script. 

I get an 'expected statement' error if I replace xlbook.close with xlbook.close SaveChanges:=True :(